# Can't convert blob to images?

Tags: php, mysqli, blob

I have an image in my local database at **id 19** in **column "profile_image"**. Now I want to fetch that image. I am using the codes below but they are not working. **"profile_image" is LONGBLOB**

```
require_once 'db.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 19;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['profile_image'] ).'"/>';

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: print $row. is there data getting?

Comment: I didn't use 'print' . But yes $row is getting data.